# Seemingly strange result for Dunn test after Kruskal-Wallis test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, p-value, kruskal-wallis-test, dunn-test

I have the following data for three treatments used on a subject. Each subject is observed and given a quality value of 1-5. The numbers in the table represent the number of subjects in each trial group that were given the corresponding quality ranking.

| Treatment | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 1 | 20 | 0 | 10 |
| b | 0 | 5 | 13 | 3 | 0 |
| c | 1 | 4 | 12 | 4 | 0 |

When I run the Kruskal-Wallis test on the above data using the statsmodels module in python,
kwStatistic, kwPvalue = stats.kruskal(*dataSetForKW)
I get that:
"The pvalue for this test is 0.00011:
and the Kruskal-Wallis test says that the medians of these data sets ARE statistically significantly different from one another."

This makes perfect sense given the data. However, when I run the Dunn posthoc test via
import scikit_posthocs as sp
p_values= sp.posthoc_dunn(np.asarray(df), p_adjust = 'bonferroni',sort = True)

to determine which of the treatments is/are responsible for this difference, I get the following output matrix:

|  | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.0 | 1.0 | 1.0 |
| 2 | 1.0 | 1.0 | 1.0 |
| 3 | 1.0 | 1.0 | 1.0 |

I interpret this to mean that the p-values for each pairing under this test are NOT significantly different from one another using this test, when treatment "a" seems to yield vastly different results from the other two.

Am I:

1. misunderstanding what the test is meant to do
2. misunderstanding how the output should be understood
3. 1 & 2 and more

Thanks for any advice you can provide.